# Swift 3 / How to call tableView.reloadData() in global function?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to refactor a function to have it globally available. At the end of the function, a `UITableView` needs to be reloaded. I was thinking about passing the VC, but I still get

> Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'tableView'

I know that I get that error because tableView is not part of a `UIViewController` by default, but how do I bypass it?

```
func downloadAvatar(_ userForAvatar: String, vc: UIViewController) {

    let whereClause = "objectId = '\(userForAvatar)'"
    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
    dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause

    let dataStore = backendless?.persistenceService.of(BackendlessUser.ofClass())
    dataStore?.find(dataQuery, response: { (users : BackendlessCollection?) in

        let withUser = users?.data.first as! BackendlessUser
        let imgURL = withUser.getProperty("Avatar") as? String
        avatare.setValue(imgURL, forKey: userForAvatar)
        vc.tableView.reloadData() // problem here

    }) { (fault : Fault?) in
        print("error: \(fault)")
    }
}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Comment: down vote at least care to comment?

Comment: Why would you want this to be a global function?

Comment: because i'm calling the exact same function in 3-4 different viewcontrollers

Comment: Consider an extension for the common superclass of the 4 view controllers. The error occurs because you're passing `UIViewController` rather than the custom subclass containing the table view.

Comment: Is an observer to prefer David?

Comment: @DavidSeek Do you meant calling, or implementing? Do those 3-4 VCs contain this function definition, or just call it?

Comment: at the moment i have implemented and called it in 3 different vcs and i want to refactor it, to just call it.

Comment: @RashwanL observer wouldnt do the trick in that case since i'm downloading data from very different sources

Comment: @vadian how would i implement that?

Comment: [The Swift Language Guide: Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html)

Comment: i know how to implement an extension and i know what an extension is, but i don't know how to implement your idea

Comment: @Callam well the error is gone, but the reload is not called

Comment: @DavidSeek wait, are you trying to call reloadData from a cell?

Comment: Create a protocol with `var tableView : UITableView {get}` and make the 4 view controllers conform to that protocol. Then write the code in the question as (protocol) extension of  `UIViewController`

Comment: @Callam no. not from a cell

Comment: okay trying the protocol approach right nw

Comment: Don't pass the view controller. Instead, pass the table view.

Comment: i got it with the protocol @vadian ,but the tableview is not reloading... the avatars are downloaded properly, a debug print statement is printed, but the tableview is not reloaded. question: does `var tableView : UITableView {get}` instantiate a second tableview object, or is the tableview object from my view controller used?

Comment: i have created a protocol with `var tableView : UITableView {get}` and i did the code from the question as protocol function extensions of my protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of have having `vc: UIViewController` as an argument, you should just have `tv: UITableView` instead. Then instead of passing the view controller, you pass it's tableView. Although if this isn't working, you could try a completion block instead.

```
func downloadAvatar(_ userForAvatar: String, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {

    let whereClause = "objectId = '\(userForAvatar)'"
    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
    dataQuery.whereClause = whereClause

    let dataStore = backendless?.persistenceService.of(BackendlessUser.ofClass())
    dataStore?.find(dataQuery, response: { (users : BackendlessCollection?) in

        let withUser = users?.data.first as! BackendlessUser
        let imgURL = withUser.getProperty("Avatar") as? String
        avatare.setValue(imgURL, forKey: userForAvatar)
        completion()

    }) { (fault : Fault?) in
        print("error: \(fault)")
    }
}
```

Then assuming you're calling this method from the respective view controller, you can reload the tableView data within the completion block.

```
downloadAvatar("$uid") { [weak self] in
     self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. the completion block was a good idea.

Comment: i just had to change it to : `completion: @escaping ()` , because of swift 3

Answer (score 3):

> 'UIViewController' has no member 'tableView'

It tells everything ! Your `vc`is of type `UIViewController` , obviously it has no member named `tableView`.

You have used the parameter vc only once and its for reloading table. So instead of passing it, try passing the tableveiew reference itself.

Because of some reasons, if you cant do this and you should use ViewController itself, try create a protocol, implement it in all of your VCs and use that as type. tableview should be a member of that protocol

This is basic programming. Hope this helps

Comment: like i said, i know why i get the error, but the idea of passing the tableView is great. trying it, but for some reason, no reload is called

Comment: What happens when you pass the tableView instead of the viewController? So the function would be `func downloadAvatar(_ userForAvatar: String, tv: UITableView)` and you'd `tv.reloadData()`

Comment: the tableview simply not reloads. i tried it with an protocol extension. same. but calling it with a completion blog did it then